# How to set system variable using java

Tags: java

I could use `System.getenv(String name)` to get the environment variable, I would ask how to set  environment variable with java?

I didn't find such method defined in the `System` class

Comment: As that environment variable would only be propagated to child processes of your Java program anyway, such a method would essentially be useless.

Comment: You need yo use System.setProperty(key, value)